# Shell Sort implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, shellsort

I understood the concept behind Shell Sort but I am finding below implementation very vague and confusing.

```
public class Shell {
    public static void sort(Comparable[] a) { // Sort a[] into increasing order.
        int N = a.length;
        int h = 1;
        while (h < N / 3) h = 3 * h + 1; // 1, 4, 13, 40, 121, 364, 1093, ...
        while (h >= 1) { // h-sort the array.
            for (int i = h; i < N; i++) { // Insert a[i] among a[i-h], a[i-2*h], a[i-3*h]... .
                for (int j = i; j >= h && less(a[j], a[j - h]); j -= h)
                    exch(a, j, j - h);
            }
            h = h / 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me in understanding the code.

Thanks

Comment: It's not vague, but it's certainly not written for understanding. I suggest you read [Shellsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort) and study their pseudocode implementation. That will give you a much better understanding than some horribly written Java code you picked up somewhere.

Comment: Sure I will read more about Shellsort. This code is from the book 'Algorithms, 4th Edition by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne'.

Comment: Do you understand that two for-loops perform insertion sort of array subsequence?

Comment: I went through some youtube videos about Shell Sort, and able to figure it out. Thanks.